# Errors de-crypting libsodium encrypted values from database

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, development

I've been implementing some encryption at rest in one of our Joomla components, but keep getting a couple of errors when de-crypting the values when they're written and read from a database.

So I wrote a basic wrapper class for crypt...

```
/**
 * This class provides functions related to encryption
 *
 * @since  2.5
 */
class crypt
{

    public $cipher = FALSE;

    public function __construct()
    {

        # test private key
        $private_key_string = "51111110024135111761721919212413";
        # test public key
        $public_key_string = "76172191921241351111110024135111";

        # get the cipher object
        $cipher = new JCryptCipherSodium;
        # generate a key
        $key = $cipher->generateKey();
        # set the nonce
        $cipher->setNonce(\Sodium\randombytes_buf(\Sodium\CRYPTO_BOX_NONCEBYTES));

        # set the key values
        $key->private = $private_key_string;
        $key->public  = $public_key_string;

        $this->key = $key;
        $this->cipher = $cipher;
        return TRUE;
    }

    public function en($string){
        #echo  "\n\nencrypt\n";
        $key = $this->key;
        $encrypted = $this->cipher->encrypt($string, $key);
        #echo  "encrypted: " . $encrypted . "\n";
        return $encrypted;
    }

    public function de($string){
        #echo  "\n\ndecrypt\n";
        $key = $this->key;
        $decrypted = $this->cipher->decrypt($string, $key);
        #echo  "decrypted: " . $decrypted . "\n";
        return $decrypted;
    }
}
```

I know this is not best practice, with keys, but I was just starting off as a proof of concept.

This works fine with a simple encrypt then decrypt, like...

```
JLoader::register("crypt","cli/crypt_helper.php");      

$crypt = new crypt();
$enc = $crypt->en("hello world, how you doing");
$de = $crypt->de($enc);
echo "de: " . $de . "\n";
```

...but when I write to a database and read back, I get the errors mentioned above. So with code like...

```
# database test
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
# Insert columns.
$columns = array('f1',);
# Insert values.
$values = array($db->quote( $crypt->en( $test_value ) ) );
# Prepare the insert query.
$query
    ->insert($db->quoteName('#__piota_results'))
    ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
    ->values(implode(',', $values));
# Set the query using our newly populated query object and execute it.
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();

# Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
# Order it by the ordering field.
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('f1')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__piota_results'));
$query->order('id DESC');
$query->setLimit('1');
# Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
$db->setQuery($query);
# Load the results as a list of stdClass objects (see later for more options on retrieving data).
$result = $db->loadResult();

echo "result: " . $result . "\n";
echo "result: " . $crypt->de( $result ) . "\n";
```

I've tried on two different systems, with slightly different errors.

System 1

- PHP 7.2.6
- Joomla! 3.8.8
- MariaDB 5.5.5-10.1.34

System 1 error message: *Invalid MAC* this is, I think, coming from https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/9ae0742f28faa1d4b5d4ae4a84619f115ed3f9ea/libraries/vendor/paragonie/sodium_compat/src/Crypto.php#L1004

System 2

- PHP 7.2.6
- Joomla! 3.8.6
- MySQL 5.7.22

System 2 error message: *Argument 1 must be at least CRYPTO_BOX_MACBYTES long* which is, I think, coming from https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/9ae0742f28faa1d4b5d4ae4a84619f115ed3f9ea/libraries/vendor/paragonie/sodium_compat/src/Compat.php#L1069

The database field is of the type "longtext" with collation "utf8mb4_bin".

I did some reading, but since libsodium is quite new in Joomla, there is not so much docs or info on it.

I tried using base64_encode and base64_decode in-case MySQL was making a mess of the data, but it was all the same.

I looked at...

- https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/16754
- https://github.com/paragonie/sodium_compat
- http://php.net/manual/en/book.sodium.php

...but with no luck.

Any ideas, thoughts or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks ❤️

Once I get this all working I'll try and write a wiki page on libsodium on https://docs.joomla.org

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This works fine with a simple encrypt then decrypt, like...
>
> ...but when I write to a database and read back, I get the errors mentioned above.

This is actually expected behavior, because the nonce isn't being stored with the ciphertext. You can verify this by [how SodiumCipher is defined](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/6de2b00858e91bd64e7c410a6ed617d455f62d64/libraries/src/Crypt/Cipher/SodiumCipher.php).

Try storing the nonce alongside the ciphertext and using it when decrypting. (Don't reuse nonces for multiple rows.)

Also, you **will** want to encode before storing and decode after retrieving (as your question alluded to), using base64 or hex.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Scott, and thanks for libsodium in Joomla, it's awesome ☺️  Great pointers, thank you, and I'll read up some more on the docs.

Answer (score 3):

The error messages `Invalid MAC` and `Argument 1 must be at least CRYPTO_BOX_MACBYTES long` are definitely misleading.

I had to try it for myself in order to find that both errors appear randomly based on the content of the string.

Despite what I expected, `$db->quote()` does NOT encode correctly the string returned by crypt. `base64_encode/decode` are sufficient: see my whole code (I changed to the `#__banners` table, for ease of testing)

```
$helperPath = dirname(__FILE__) ."/crypt_helper.php";
JLoader::register("crypt",$helperPath);      
$test_value = 'the <b>quick brown fox jumps</b> over the lazy dog<br>';
$crypt = new crypt();

# database test
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$columns = array('name','params');
$values = array($db->quote('test'), $db->quote( 
    base64_encode( $crypt->en( $test_value ) )
    ));

# Prepare the insert query.
$query
    ->insert($db->quoteName('#__banners'))
    ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
    ->values(implode(',',$values));
# Set the query using our newly populated query object and execute it.
echo $query .'<br>'; 
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();

# Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
# Order it by the ordering field.
$query->select($db->quoteName('params'));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__banners'));
$query->order('id DESC');
$query->setLimit('1');
# Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
$db->setQuery($query);
# Load the results as a list of stdClass objects (see later for more options on retrieving data).
$result = $db->loadResult();

echo "result: " . $result . "\n";
echo "result: " . $crypt->de( base64_decode($result )) . "\n";

die();
```

These is the video output of the query, inserted and retrieved data:

```
INSERT INTO `#__banners`
(`name`,`params`) VALUES 
('test','pKihow6a5Dfx/7p+dlGc5qOnBgOvoJ3+TcZu82sCQU/EWYxnsdxRiAJ6cjB2l433LlSOgTWT0i1Sn/uAWdy/hzwRlRUKaQ==')

result: pKihow6a5Dfx/7p+dlGc5qOnBgOvoJ3+TcZu82sCQU/EWYxnsdxRiAJ6cjB2l433LlSOgTWT0i1Sn/uAWdy/hzwRlRUKaQ==

result: the <b>quick brown fox jumps</b> over the lazy dog<br>
```

**Note 1:** any attempt without base64_encode fails. I tried it with 10 bytes or 1K of text and it works just fine.

**Note 2:** `$db->insertObject()` is much easier to use than your approach, it handles the `$db->quote()` calls for you, **but still requires base64_encode**:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$object = new stdClass();
$object->name = 'test';
$object->params = base64_encode($crypt->en( $test_value ));
$db->insertObject('#__banners', $object);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Riccardo, and for taking time out to recreate it.  I'll try these tweaks over the next couple of days.